Put data from smaller xarray dataset into larger one based on lat/lon?
I'm working with xarray. I have two datasets with lat/lon/depth coordinates. The smaller dataset is a subset of the larger one (e.g. if latitude range of the larger one is 20-30°E, smaller one is 24-26°E, with matching instances). The smaller dataset contains actual data and I wish to copy those onto the larger dataset. Any help? Thanks!
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

nc = xr.open_dataset("big_set.nc") #contains only one slice of the 4D data (time, depth, lat, lon)
nc1 = xr.open_dataset("small_set.nc") #contains all slices of 4D data at smaller spatial extent

lat = nc.latitude
lon = nc.longitude
depth = nc.depth
time = nc1.time[0 : nc1.time.size//10] 

data = np.zeros((time.size, depth.size, lat.size, lon.size)) #dummy data



ds = xr.DataArray(data = data, dims = ['time', 'depth','lat', 'lon'], coords = {'time': time.data, 'depth': depth.data, 'lat': lat.data, 'lon': lon.data})

